# How do I create invites with usage limit to a private channel on Telegram with Telethon?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

I'm using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/) to create a Telegram BOT and I needed to automate a task of generating a one time use invite

I tried searching about it but didn't find anything at their [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/) neither stackoverflow (i did find somethings about invites with this library but didn't understood how to handle my situation)

Anything that may help me with this is welcome!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [telethon.dev](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/export_chat_invite.html), You can mod the example like:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

session_file_name = ""        # TODO: session file name without extension
api_id = ""                   # TODO: api id 
api_hash = ""                 # TODO: api hash 
channel_id = -1001109500936   # TODO: channel ID 

with TelegramClient(session_file_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.ExportChatInviteRequest(
        peer=client.get_input_entity(channel_id),
        legacy_revoke_permanent=True,
        expire_date=None, # Set expiry date if needed like datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 25),
        usage_limit=1     # Only one person can use your invite link
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```